# I want only the files that contain def to be displayed. But this code displays all files. How to solve?

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to display as "file name def statements..." But this code is not helping.

```
  files = Dir.entries("C:\\Users\\itcuser\\Desktop\\Ruby Programs").select {|f| !File.directory? f}
    files.each do |file_name|
      if !File.directory? file_name   
        File.open(file_name) do |f|
         **puts file_name**
         f.any? do |line|     
          if line.include?("def")
           print line
       end
        end
      end
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
files = Dir.entries("C:\\Users\\itcuser\\Desktop\\Ruby Programs")
files.each do |file_name|
  # skip this, if file_name is a directory
  next if File.directory? file_name   

  lines = File.readlines(filename)
  puts file_name if lines.any? { |line| line.include?('def') 
end
```

Comment: Thanks sir! But it is still printing all files-> that is-> which does not include def statements in the files. I want only the names of the files that includes def statements

Comment: This code will perform quite poorly on large files.

Comment: It works! It displays the files that includes "def statements". I also want the statements that are present in the file.

eg: filename
def 1
def 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not using the return value of your `f.any?` to print the filename. Should be more like this instead.

```
File.open(file_name) do |f|
  puts file_name if f.any? { |line| line.include?("def") }
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I replaced in my code. There is a small error though. The first def statement doesn't display. So if a file has only one def statement, it is not getting displayed.

Comment: @SurabhiGowdaK: Not sure why that would happen. Must be something else in your code that interferes with this.

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if f.any? { |line| line.include?("def") }

There is problem with this part. It isn't displaying the first if statement.